# Backup Fails after upgrade to 20.04

Tags: upgrade, backup, gvfs

First backup after upgrading to 20.04: when I try to start my backup, it asks me to install **gvfs-backends**. When accept to proceed with the installation, I obtain the following error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
gvfs-backends: Depends: libsmbclient (>= 2:4.10.0+dfsg) but 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.20 is to be installed
```

Comment: I think you somehow messed up your package sources lists. `2:4.7.6` is the current version for `18.04`. `20.04` has `2:4.11.6`. Use `apt policy libsmbclient` to check which sources are used. Or see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories) how to restore the default sources if you cannot fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update + Solution

As suggested by pLumo in the comments my /etc/apt/sources.list was quite messed up: it was still using the old version for Ubuntu 18.04 (2:4.7.6). Therefore I have followed [these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories) to regenerate a new sources.list (which for Ubuntu 20.04 can be found [here](https://dannyda.com/2020/10/03/default-contents-of-sources-list-in-ubuntu-20-04-1-lts-desktop-server/?__cf_chl_captcha_tk__=67441dedf60527db58f8ba0d0377b262c7ee849f-1605091417-0-AaxVvaG5qXxVvMzsBXjA-8I_ByGJf9P4CU_pN5n6JLxNeCrLN2X2zshzn4RRQh5YqLp23Ugb0tDxpHWHUFIJJFZLqzj0Z2bR0rkgIzUqUDX7gVD-cM9NItSEjZTuXgbMi4QuLmnozQomjXeQlSITubk6o9ikm0JuHiT0Qnlp4OPbzcyFmwIvbpdJEJXeRVOP01kbbD_Rr0J8qeTm692FQq8NQXkFDOzt8EINs7DeTkcfbTTCpIPGJ6tFg58wVk4rzoaF7kf2n2Z5_SV_Xs1zMHv_BNpSCghIPDVDfW6WdAdo_PqhhQnxt_hErCMwmNZVNIOpg3hcF8k9_Mdqrj1Ue9PV9H0Wp0PKvDi8jzsm0XY6wxUrn4tT_6VFlS2-87ILk0g_jx3Y-75SzVx_uRyFCNUut7pSm6_RzICETXFeIpfGBe29pL8AicZNDi8-5w7iTBGpkeCnOqd4tdwerMmRUCJB_wmVXt0hbG7nbkcaOZJeVHcMPmAZ6nx5DUBm_mLkBF1yfTMYdo6Y1mzBvFgSw2JJu1ws2nV7YxRq8KVfb591m2phLmEDKfuQkACFAI6CCibjFyW-2BoY0ITpMA5S_Hg)).